# How to switch rendering engine via python script

Tags: rendering, python

I managed to compile Blender as a Python import module. When I do `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` it renders with cycles. How can I render by using Blender internal renderer instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the engine before rendering like this:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'
```

Its possible multiple scenes are involved in the render so you may want to do...

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'
```

***Note:*** If you select the *Scripting* screen, then change the engine, the code to do this is printed at the top of the screen (called the *Info* view), eg:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
```

Comment: ! Thanks for the helpful hints about using a for loop to enforce all scene to be rendered by using Blender internal renderer.